# How to prevent AppletClassLoader from hitting the server when looking for classes/other resources?

Tags: java, applet

I am developing a web application that relies heavily on Applets. Some third party code causes several, in some cases hundreds of, remote lookups of classes and some other resources from the server. This results in a significant performance issue. I've built my own code such that if something is NOT found within the .jar, it is not needed.

Does anyone know of a decent way to prevent the remote lookups (besides making sure all the stuff I see in my access logs is actually in the .jar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try experimenting with the codebase_lookup parameter mentioned in [Special Applet Attributes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html).